# gets() function using getchar from assembly

Tags: c, assembly, dos, x86-16

I'm having some problems making a `gets()` function on a C code i'm doing for one of my classes. So i already have a `getchar()` function but on assembly and i'm calling it from C using `extern` The thing is that at the moment i'm running the code i enter a string and it doesn't show the complete string instead some characters.

This is the code i have atm:
C code:

```
extern char getchar(void);
extern void putchar(char data);
void gets(char *str);
void puts(char *str);
void new_line();

char string[20];

int main(){
    while(1){
        gets(string);
        new_line();
        puts(string);
    }
    return 0;
}

void new_line(){
    putchar(0xD);
    putchar(0xA);
}
void gets(char *str){
    unsigned char i = 0;
    while((*str = getchar()) != 0xD){
        str[i] = getchar();
        i++;
    }
}

void puts(char *str){
    while(*str){
        putchar(*str++);
    }
}
```

and my ASM code just in case:

```
.MODEL tiny

.CODE
    public _putchar
    public _getchar

    _putchar    PROC
                push bp
                mov bp, sp
                mov dl, [bp + 4]
                mov ah, 2
                int 21h
                pop bp
                ret
    _putchar    ENDP

    _getchar    PROC
                push bp
                mov bp, sp
                mov ah, 1
                int 21h
                mov [bp + 4], al
                pop bp
                ret
    _getchar    ENDP
END
```

I'm running the code on an Arduino Mega using MTTTY with an 8086 interpreter that our teacher provided.

Any way i can solve this issue with the gets() function so i can show the input string properly?

For example if i enter "hello world" it only prints "l ol"

Comment: After a brief look, your while-condition in `gets` doesn't seem to match the body.  This: `(*str = getchar()) != 0xD` implies that the body should be `str++`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Your C `gets` implementation is broken**, regardless of the asm `getchar` implementation.  You could debug it on a normal C implementation with a normal debugger on your desktop.

You call `getchar()` twice, and only save every 2nd result.

The first result is assigned to `str[0]` and checked for `'\r'`.

```
// your version with comments
void gets_original_buggy (char *str){
    unsigned char i = 0;   // this is an index; it should be an `int` or `size_t`

    while((*str = getchar()) != 0xD){  // overwrite the first byte of the string with an input
        str[i] = getchar();    // get ANOTHER new input and save it to the end.
        i++;
    }
    // str[i] = 0;  // missing zero terminator.
}
```

**Here's how I'd write it:**

```
#include <stddef.h>
//#include <stdio.h>

extern unsigned char getchar(void);

// returns length.
// negative means EOF.  TODO: implement an EOF check if your getchar() supports it.
// FIXME: take a max-length arg to make it possible to prevent buffer overflows.
ptrdiff_t gets(char *str) {
    char *start = str;  // optional

    char tmp;  // read chars into a local, and check before assigning anything to *str
    while( (tmp = getchar()) != '\r') {
        // TODO: also check for EOF
        *str++ = tmp;            // classic pointer post-increment idiom
    }
    *str = 0;     // terminate the C string.

    return str - start;  // optional, return the length
}
```

It's always useful to return the string length instead of throwing it away in a function that knows it, and this only costs the compiler a couple extra instructions.  The pointer increment simplifies the addressing mode, saving code-size.

(compiles nicely with [gcc and clang for 32-bit x86 on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cstddef.h%3E%0A//%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0Aextern+unsigned+char+getchar(void)%3B%0A%0A//+returns+length.%0A//+negative+means+EOF.++TODO:+implement+an+EOF+check+if+your+getchar()+supports+it.%0A//+FIXME:+take+a+max-length+arg+to+make+it+possible+to+prevent+buffer+overflows.%0Aptrdiff_t+gets(char+*str)+%7B%0A++++char+*start+%3D+str%3B++//+optional%0A%0A++++char+tmp%3B++//+read+chars+into+a+local,+and+check+before+assigning+anything+to+*str%0A++++while(+(tmp+%3D+getchar())+!!%3D+!'%5Cr!')+%7B%0A++++++++*str%2B%2B+%3D+tmp%3B++++++++++++//+classic+pointer+post-increment+idiom%0A++++%7D%0A++++*str+%3D+0%3B+++++//+terminate+the+C+string.%0A%0A++++return+str+-+start%3B++//+optional,+return+the+length%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:33.20244328097732,l:'4',m:100,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-m32',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:33.46422338568936,l:'4',m:68.76876876876878,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+gcc+8.2',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:31.231231231231227,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:34.91328143547963,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang600,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-m64',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+6.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:31.884275283543047,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), should be pretty similar for x86-16.)

You might also/instead check for `'\n'` depending on your getchar implementation, and whether it normalizes line endings or not.  And remember that stopping after reading a `\r` will leave a `\n` unread if you have DOS `"\r\n"` line endings.

In ISO C, `getchar()` should give you only `'\n'` line endings for files opened in text mode, but you've made `getchar` just a wrapper around DOS [`int 21h` / AH=1](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah01) (READ CHARACTER FROM STANDARD INPUT, WITH ECHO) function.  So that's what sets the behaviour of your implementation.

### asm bug:

```
# in _getchar:
    mov [bp + 4], al         ; clobber memory you don't own.
```

That will clobber memory above the return address.  `char getchar(void)` doesn't take any args, so your function doesn't "own" that memory.  Your compiler should expect a return value in AL.  (And if you thought that was returning by reference, no, you're just overwriting the pointer arg.  Except the caller isn't even passing one.)

If you want your `getchar` to be able to return EOF distinct from a `0xFF` byte, declare it as returning `int`, and zero AH after making the system call.  (So you can return a 16-bit `-1` in AX, or a zero-extended `unsigned char` in AX (i.e. value in AL).

---

BTW, **there's a reason [`gets()` is deprecated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/gets), and actually *removed* in ISO C11**: it's impossible to prevent buffer overflows when reading unknown-length input.

Your function should take a size limit as a 2nd arg.

---

Programming an Arduino's AVR or ARM CPU *directly* would probably be easier to learn, and more useful, than using DOS system calls on an emulated 8086.  If you're going to do that, there's no point in doing it on real hardware vs. a simulator.

Learning x86 as your first assembly language is ok if you don't mess around with segmentation, and you don't try to write a bootloader (there's lots of arcane legacy stuff with the A20 gate, and switching from real mode to protected mode).  DOS system calls are totally obsolete, except for maintaining legacy codebases.  Learning the details of how the different AH=?? / `int 21h` system calls work exactly is about as useful as COBOL.  The BIOS `int 10h` and other families are slightly more useful if you're making a legacy boot sector (instead of EFI), but you don't need to do that to learn asm.  If you learn asm in user-space under Linux, Windows, Mac, *BSD, or whatever, it becomes easy to understand / learn other ways of communicating with the outside world later, if you ever need to, and learn how kernels work.

Linux system calls have a similar ABI (`eax=call number` / `int 0x80`, `sysenter`, or `syscall`), but Linux system calls are more or less POSIX system calls that it is useful to know about for real-world low-level programming.

The complexities of POSIX TTY line-buffered input with `sys_read` are different from the complexities of DOS character-reading functions and line-ending nonsense, but arguably more useful to learn.

Comment: `getchar()` should read `\n` for line-endings if the file is opened in text-mode, and whatever is native otherwise. But, is it actually so ancient that doesn't hold? Also, you fail to allow for `getchar()` returning an error.

Comment: @Deduplicator: The OP is using a custom `getchar()` implementation using [DOS `int 21h` / AH=1](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah01).  I don't know if that API has a text vs. binary mode option, or what it does for EOF.  Good point, though, I should return `ptrdiff_t` so a negative can mean EOF.

Comment: DOS system calls are totally obsolete.So on DOS what do you recommend - reinventing the wheel and rewrite the DOS calls yourself or try and replace them with BIOS calls? If you are using DOS, these system calls aren't obsolete.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: That's my point: I wouldn't recommend using DOS or legacy BIOS to teach asm in the first place, or teaching 8086.  32-bit user-space x86 with opaque input/output functions provided by the instructor (like Irvine32) seems easier, and doesn't force you to learn 16-bit addressing mode restrictions.   Or like I said, AVR or ARM asm with opaque instructor-provided I/O functions would work too.  (And BTW, I already moved that rant to the bottom of my answer, instead of the top, while you were commenting.  I decided it didn't need to be there.)

Comment: No, that's not what was said. You said DOS system calls are obsolete. My point was that if you are **using** DOS the system calls being used are NOT obsolete. What you may have meant is that DOS was obsolete which isn't even true but you can continue to fly that banner. Projects like FreeDOS don't exist just to be cool or retro. They can be adapted to embedded millspec processors that have the functionality of an 80186.

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I'd compare learning DOS system calls in 2018 to learning COBOL in 2018: yes there is still some production code using it, but AFAIK no new code.  I'd call that obsolete.  Anyway, I already reworded my answer to say that, and that this seems to me like a silly way to teach asm.  I'm not going to defend the first version of what I posted, because you're right, it was too strong a claim that just dumped on DOS because I don't like it and have never seen the point of using it (I didn't use PCs until Linux existed).  There's still a good helping of that in my current answer though.

Comment: You didn't reword it, as it still says "DOS system calls are totally obsolete". DOS System calls being used here are NOT obsolete when using DOS.

Comment: Would be like declaring 32-bit Linux obsolete (a suggestion you have made previously) but telling people  who still program on 32-bit Linux that `int 0x80` is obsolete. What would be the recommendation? Avoid using the kernel API?

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I see your point.  I did already add "except for maintaining legacy codebases", which I think is the only reason someone would be writing DOS code.  Or do people still pick DOS for new development of firmware-update utilities or something?  And they write asm by hand instead of using compilers / library functions?  I'm trying to say that learning the API details of how it signals EOF and so on aren't useful to most people, because avoiding DOS entirely is a fully valid option, and one that I'd recommend, especially for beginners learning asm.

Comment: @PeterCordes DOS is healthy and alive, if you have an x86 based computer that motherboard was likely developed and tested using DOS first then other operating systems later.  Production/ mfg test likely uses DOS as well.  Nothing has really been able to touch it as far as embedded operating systems, we are finally starting to see cash registers and gas pumps and other systems that were using DOS until recently use something else (embedded windows which is just scary).   So development is cutting back and is likely limited to the mfg of x86 computers going forward.

Comment: But it is certainly not limited to legacy code bases.